# How to organize text files in Java

Tags: java, file

So i have an assignment in which i have to create several text files, and be able to put these text files into categories. I only know how to create a text file to the default location in eclipse. I am unaware on how to create a text file to a certain location. Could someone perhaps lead me in the right direction on how to organize text files into specific folders?

Comment: I'd start with google

Answer (score 2):

Use the `File` class to specify the place of the file.

```
File file = new File("C:/Users/Jordan/Documents", "a_text_file.txt");
file.createNewFile();
```

Then use your preferred method of writing to this file.

Comment: Maybe add File(String parent, String child) to your example.

Answer (score 2):

Here's [one way](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/io/bufferedwriter/write-file-with-bufferedwriter-example/) to write to a directed file.  Notice the filepath String.

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

public class BufferedWriterExample {

    private static String filepath = "C:\\Users\\nikos7\\Desktop\\words.txt";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try { 
            String content = "JavaCodeGeeks is the best!";

            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = 
                    new BufferedWriter(newFileWriter(filepath));
            bufferedWriter.write(content);
            bufferedWriter.close();

            System.out.println("The file was successfully updated");

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To read, you can use `Scanner`. To write, you can use `FileWriter`.

```
final File file = new File("file.txt");
// file = new File("C:\\", "file.txt");
// file = new File("C:\\" + File.SEPERATOR + "file.txt");

try(final FileWriter w=new FileWriter(file)){
  w.write(string);
}
catch(final Exception e){
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

> Specified by:
>
> http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html

Comment: Maybe add File(String parent, String child)  to your example.